# Non-Temporal Load (MOVNTDQA) operand type, alignment, and asm syntax

Tags: gcc, assembly, simd, inline-assembly, avx

I'm trying to execute a non-temporal load using the `VMOVNTDQA` instruction on a data array that has been allocated using `posix_memalign()` (assume this is write-combining by changing the library), with the alignment done to 16B. However I keep getting segfaults. uint64 and uint128 are of typedef long long and __int128 respectively. Here's a code snippet:

```
uint64* arr;
posix_memalign((void**) &arr, 16, arr_size * sizeof(uint64))
uint128 b;
//index is a uint64 type and calculated earlier 
asm volatile ("vmovntdqa %1, %0" : "=x" (b) : "m" (arr[index]));
//additional code working on b here, result stored back to arr[index]
```

The `VMOVNTDQA` spec says that the instruction is of type `VMOVNTDQA xmm1, m128`, and addresses must be 128-bit (16-byte) aligned. Now the above code is aligning the addresses to 16B. The above code works fine and does not give any segfaults if arr if of type uint128. However, I should be able to load a 128-bit value from a 64-bit element array if it is aligned.

My question is whether the segfault occurs due to m128 only accepting __int128 type elements? or is it an alignment issue? or is there a problem with the above asm syntax?

Thanks

Comment: If your `index` is odd then the address will be unaligned.

Comment: For the record, `vmovntdqa` doesn't do anything special on current CPUs unless you use it on WC memory (uncacheable write-combining, like video RAM).  Actual `posix_memalign`  will only ever alloc normal WB memory.  Use `prefetchntdqa` if you want to play around with reducing cache pollution for normal loads.  If you can mmap some WC memory then that's fine, although probably lower performance than SW NT prefetch on WB memory.

Comment: Also, use intrinsics not inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have a modified version of posix_memalign() for WC memory.

Comment: @Jester I am forced to use the inline asm (I have to play around and measure cycle counts)

Comment: @mas: just read your question in more detail and modified my previous comment.

Comment: You can count core cycles and/or time (TSC reference cycles) for a compiler-generated asm loop; most of us who do performance tuning do that routinely.  Using inline asm will (hopefully) lead to the same end result asm output, or worse if the compiler can't optimize around your asm statement as well.

Comment: @Jester Actually your first comment fixed the segfault. Thank You. However I always thought that adding an odd address should only give a segfault when I'm going out of bounds? Why cant I just access 128-bits from anywhere in aligned memory?

Comment: There is no such thing as "aligned memory". The only address the instruction cares about is the one you give it. Aligning the allocation just ensures that you have a known starting point. You still need an offset that maintains that alignment.