# Allocation array in Ram, no cache misses, C/C++

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory-management, ram

Is there a way to say to the compiler:

"do not try looking for it in the different caches and miss each time. Go for the RAM"

That way it should be faster to access to a huge array, which most probably would be stored there nevertheless.

This is under the assumption it is stored in the RAM from the beginning. I read CPU loads chunk of bytes, so if I need to access to an array element, do some operations with it and access another one, is it going to make cache misses or is it not necessary? Is it going to load a chunk of x bytes from the array each time, so that when it reaches the end of the chunk, the next one is stored in the cache automatically?

Let us think of a 10^9 floats array.

Comment: To my knowledge, not only there is no way to do that in C++ language, but there is no way in assembly language neither. And anyway, **you don't want that**. Even in your case, cache will be useful unless you access the array in a completely random way.

Comment: That's not something a compiler is able to do, it's all handled by the CPU itself. The compiler can only emit instructions to load data from a specific memory location (a virtual address on most systems), it's then the CPU that translates that into an actual location in RAM (with the help of tables set up by the OS), which may of may not be in the cache. Or worse, it might be swapped out to disk.

Comment: A cache miss is expensive not because of the lookup but because then you need to go to the RAM and wait for that. Avoiding the lookup would save more or less nothing.

Comment: I think that on arm64 you can mark memory pages as non-cacheable using privileged instructions, in that case each access should go directly on the memory bus. I agree with prapin that you do not want this. A lot of thought went into speeding up memory access as transparently to the user as possible, do you really know better?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I understood. I didn't know well how cache worked and that the actual heavy lifting was not the miss, but the access to a much more peripheral memory.

Comment: To answer the rest of your questions. Access to RAM is usually done in at least cache lines - 64B.  So if you access nearby elements, they will be in cache - this is what makes linear access the fastest. Yes, CPU together with compiler can do *some* prefetching but this is really specific. In summary, you should already get the best performance you can given the access patterns, so you should optimize the access patterns to be cache-friendly - as much linear as little randomness as possible.

Comment: There is in fact an option to do something like what you describe: Memory operations with non-temporal hints. With the Intel intrinsics this would be [`_mm_stream_load_si128`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=6095,4338,4340,3859,104,3859,3856,280,3871,3871,5038,5042&text=stream) (and similarly named operations), and for writing `_mm_stream_ps`. I've used streaming writes to get great performance improvements in the past but I do not have performance figures for streaming loads.

Comment: On further research: Peter answers on the usefulness of streaming loads (or lack thereof) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510191/does-anyone-have-an-example-where-mm256-stream-load-si256-non-tempral-load-to Again, streaming writes can work, see for example here https://vgatherps.github.io/2018-09-02-nontemporal/

Comment: There is no standard way to do this and whether or not it would be a good idea depends on the specific system. Most likely, nothing would be gained. Bypassing memory cache does have a purpose in case the memory is also accessed by [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access), but for optimization, I doubt it.

Comment: Additional relevant question: [Do current x86 architectures support non-temporal loads (from "normal" memory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40096894/580083).

Comment: If you access the memory sequentially (or in some other predictable pattern) then the CPUs prefetcher will likely read ahead and bring the next thing you need into cache automagically.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for *Non-Temporal* memory access assembly instructions such as [`vmovntdqa`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movntdqa), which tell the CPU to avoid using the cache more than necessary. This doesn't make the access faster, but it avoids pushing things out of the cache that you want to stay in the cache.

The instructions are just hints and [not always implemented on CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851286/how-to-use-movntdqa-to-avoid-cache-pollution). Exact behaviour seems difficult to research online. A [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254988/non-temporal-load-movntdqa-operand-type-alignment-and-asm-syntax) as well as [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096894/do-current-x86-architectures-support-non-temporal-loads-from-normal-memory) says you should use `prefetchntdqa` instead, if you want to load without using the cache. You should probably research your processor's cache behaviour in depth, and have a way to know whether it's working, before using these special instructions.

Note that these are SIMD instructions which load 128, 256 or 512 bits at a time, into an appropriately sized SIMD register, not a general purpose register.

It seems you need to use inline assembly to make GCC generate these instructions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating memory doesn’t touch any memory. It just reserves space in the logical address space.

If you think there is data that you access exactly once and there is no point in caching it, there are processors with instructions that read or write data without changing the “least recently used” information. So the data enters a tiny amount of the cache and is thrown out again very quickly.